# How to receive both File and data POSTed to an ASP.net core 2.1 Web-API endpoint

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to upload a **file** and some **data** (list of objects) to an ASP.net core 2.1 web-api endpoint.

This code below generates and sends the expected payload correctly:

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', this.file)
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(this.mappings))

axios.post('upload', formData)
// {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}} optional ???
```

The payload looks like this: *(as seen in chrome dev-tools, network tab)*

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydAP5tYG5GcFa4ivU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Master-List.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundarydAP5tYG5GcFa4ivU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[{"required":true,"type":"field","value":"code","col":1,"text":"Item Code"},{"required":true,"type":"field","value":"name","col":2,"text":"Description"},{"required":true,"type":"field","value":"barcode","col":3,"text":"Barcode"},{"type":"field","value":"category","col":null,"text":"Category"},{"type":"field","value":"unit","col":null,"text":"Unit"},{"type":"location","value":1,"col":6,"text":"Store 1"}]
------WebKitFormBoundarydAP5tYG5GcFa4ivU--
```

The Web-api endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
//[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public Task<ActionResult> _upload([FromForm] Upload obj)
{
    // do something
    return Ok();
}

public class Upload
{
    public Field[] data { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public int col { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to receive the **`file`**, but the **`data`** is always empty.

Please what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there appears to be no out-of-the-box solution for sending JSON data to an ASP.NET Core MVC endpoint, it is possible to to format the data as a set of key-value pairs that will be parsed into your `Fields[]` as expected. It looks a little bit like this (name = value):

```
data[<index>][<key>] = value
```

Here's a code sample that builds up the `FormData` using explicit property keys:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.mappings.length; i++) {
    formData.append(`data[${i}][col]`, this.mappings[i].col);
    formData.append(`data[${i}][type]`, this.mappings[i].type);
    formData.append(`data[${i}][value]`, this.mappings[i].value);
}
```

This builds something that looks a bit like this:

```
data[0][col] = value
data[0][type] = value
data[0][value] = value
```

Here's an extended code sample that iterates over the properties, rather than using explicit keys:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.mappings.length; i++) {
    for (let k in this.mappings[i]) {
        formData.append(`data[${i}][${k}]`, this.mappings[i][k]);
    }
}
```

This last sample assumes that you want *all iterable properties of each mapping* - there are a number of different ways to do this in JavaScript that I will not enumerate here. If your mapping is a simple object, the code I've provided should suffice.

Overall, this is more verbose both in the code and in the number of *parts* being send to the ASP.NET Core MVC endpoint. The benefit is that the endpoint can just receive a strongly-typed model without having to perform any extra parsing of JSON, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but this modification works

```
  public class Upload
  {
    public string data { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
  }

[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<ActionResult> _upload([FromForm] Upload o)
{
  List<Field> x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>>(o.data);

  return Ok();
}
```